# SQL Query-- Change Dynamically Tomorrow's Date based on today

Tags: sqlite

I need this sql to be made dynamically, in order to change the date each day. I need the date of tomorrow all the time. If i run the query on 30th than i need  1st of October etc. I don't want the user to put the date of tomorrow manually all the time.

```
SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = "2018-09-29"
```

Thank you!

LE: The database is db.sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using SQLite, you can achieve it in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM parcare_parking WHERE parking_on = date('now','+1 day');
```

Comment: do you mean SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = DATE_ADD("2018-09-29", INTERVAL 1 DAY)?

Comment: @Cohen I've just provided syntax, but yes you can use it in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i got near "1": syntax error: SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1

Comment: Do you use MySQL?

Comment: DB Browser for SQLite or a 3rd party plugin for django

Comment: i think the format is nor ok. the records are saved like this 2018-09-27

Comment: i  have an sqlite3

Comment: @Cohen I've updated my answer with the solution for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It just does NOW() which is todays date and adds 1 day.

Comment: i got near "1": syntax error: SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = dateadd(day, 1,cast('2018-09-29' as date))
```

Comment: no such column: day: SELECT * FROM parcare_parking where parking_on = dateadd(day, 1,cast('2018-09-29' as date))

Comment: i  have an sqlite3

Comment: this is the basic idea you can do in sqlite in that way

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM parcare_parking WHERE parking_on = DATEADD(Day, 1, getnow())
```

Comment: Day isn't a column, its what tells DATEADD the unit to increase such as day, week, year, month, hour etc. You can google what DATEADD does to see more of the syntax, but simply it just adds 1 day to today (GETNOW())